# I want to ignore some fields of an object with in my class using JsonIgnore

Tags: java, javabeans

**Question:**

In next code, I just want `userId` field of `user` object to create car object from a @POST resteasy method. Can I use `@JsonIgnore`?

**Code:**

***Car.java:***

```
Public class Car {
    private int intval;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "user_id")   
    private User user;
}
```

***User.java:***

```
Public class User {
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private Long userId;
}
```

Comment: Why you expose domain objects. Create a DTO classes for User and Car then expose those DTOs the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonUnwrapped` and `@JsonProperty` together as below:

```
public class Car {

    private int intval;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "user_id")
    @JsonUnwrapped
    @JsonProperty("userId")   
    private User user;

}
```

You can find example and more info [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html).

Comment: Many Thanks Yogen. it nearly solves my problem but doing so its messing with my '@NamedQuery' as Car is an '@Entity' class and in the query car.userId cannot be resolved. I was wondering if there is way to have user objection as is in the car class but while exposing car to  api method '@Get' & '@Post' hide all user object fields except userid

Comment: @AtifKhan json marshalling and unmarshalling is only for web layer! So, for now, to solve your issue, you should use `car.user.userId` in your namedQuery :)